# Flame onLoad vs constructor initialization

Tags: flutter, flame

If I create a component in Flame like this:

```dart
class MyComponent extends PositionComponent {
  MyComponent() {
    // Option 1
  }

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() {
    // Option 2
  }
}
```

What difference does it make if I initialize my component in the constructor (Option 1) or the `onLoad` method (Option 2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have things that need to load before the component is added to the game, like an image for example, then you need to do that loading in `onLoad` so that the game knows that it shouldn't add your component to the game until everything in there is loaded. For example:

```dart
class MyComponent extends PositionComponent {
  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    final sprite = await loadSprite('flame.png');
  }
}
```

So to make your code consistent you can do all your initialization in `onLoad`, even if it is not needed for all your components.

Another good thing to know about `onLoad` is that if your are using the `HasGameRef` mixin the `gameRef` will be set to your component in `onLoad`, but not in the constructor.